# Swift,error(Argument labels '(node:)' do not match any available overloads),rest in vapor,model Controller

Tags: json, swift, postgresql, vapor

I am using postgreSQL database and vapor, fluent for relation.I am trying to make extension ´request´ for ´model´(dataPointStorage) to be in Json formate. i get the error (Argument labels '(node:)' do not match any available overloads).
code.

### dataPointController.swift

```
     import Vapor
     import HTTP

    final class dataPointController: ResourceRepresentable{

    func create(request: Request) throws -> ResponseRepresentable{
        var dataPoints = try request.dataPoints()
        try dataPoints.save()
        return dataPoints as! ResponseRepresentable
    }

    func show(request: Request, dataPoints: dataPointStorage) throws -> ResponseRepresentable {
        return dataPoints as! ResponseRepresentable
    }

    func update(request: Request, dataPoints: dataPointStorage) throws -> ResponseRepresentable {
        let new = try request.dataPoints()
        var dataPoints = dataPoints
        dataPoints.name = new.name
        dataPoints.displayName = new.displayName
        dataPoints.content = new.content
        try dataPoints.save()
        return dataPoints as! ResponseRepresentable

    }

    func delete(request: Request, dataPoints: dataPointStorage) throws -> ResponseRepresentable {
        try dataPoints.delete()
        return JSON([:])
    }
    func index(request: Request) throws -> ResponseRepresentable{

        return try JSON(node:dataPointStorage.all())
    }

    func makeResource() -> Resource<dataPointStorage> {
        return Resource(
            index: index,
            store: create,
            show: show,
            destroy: delete
        )
    }
}
extension Request{

    func dataPoints() throws -> dataPointStorage {
        guard let json = json else { throw Abort.badRequest }
        **return try dataPointStorage(node: json)** 'error(Argument labels '(node:)' do not match any available overloads)'
    }

}
```

### model.swift

```
    import Foundation
             import Vapor
             import FluentProvider
             import PostgreSQLProvider


    final class dataPointStorage: Model, JSONRepresentable, NodeRepresentable {

    //  var _data: dataPointProtocol?
    //    var _data:[dataPointProtocol] = []
        let storage = Storage()
        var id: Node?
        var name:String
        var displayName:String
           public var content: String!


        init(node:Node ,content: String, displayName:String, name:String) {
            self.id = nil
            self.content = content
            self.displayName = displayName
            self.name = name
        }

        struct Keys {
            static let id = "id"
            static let content = "content"
        }

        func forDataBase() {


            let array:[berichtDataPoint] = [intDataPoint(), boolDataPoint(), doubleDataPoint()]

            let _ = array[0] as! intDataPoint
            let _ = array[1] as! doubleDataPoint


            for point in array {

                switch point {
                case is  intDataPoint:
                    print("int")
                case is doubleDataPoint:
                    print("double")
                case is boolDataPoint:
                    print("bool")
                default:
                    print("error")
                }
            }

        }

      func makeRow() throws -> Row {
            var row = Row()
            try row.set("id", id)
            try row.set("displayName", displayName)
            try row.set("name", name)
            return row
        }

        init(row: Row) throws {
            content = try row.get("content")
            displayName = try row.get("displayName")
            name = try row.get("name")
        }

        func makeNode(context: Context) throws -> Node {
            return try Node(node: [
                "id": id,
                "content": content,
                "displayName": displayName,
                "name": name
                ])
        }
    }

    extension dataPointStorage: Preparation {
        static func prepare(_ database: Database) throws {
            try database.create(self) { dataPointStorage in
                dataPointStorage.id()
                dataPointStorage.string("displayName")
                dataPointStorage.string("name")
                dataPointStorage.string("content")

            }
        }

        static func revert(_ database: Database) throws {
            try database.delete(dataPointStorage)
        }
    }

    extension dataPointStorage: JSONConvertible {
        convenience init(json: JSON) throws {
            try self.init(
                **content: json.get(dataPointStorage.content)**
error(Instance member 'content' cannot be used on type 'dataPointStorage')
            )
        }
        func makeJSON() throws -> JSON {
            var json = JSON()
            try json.set("name", name)
            try json.set("displaName", displayName)
            try json.set("content", Content)
            return json
        }
```

Also in Model the i am using extension dataPointStorage: JSONConvertible ,in which convenience init is not getting the content while i already defined the var content as public,
I dont know where i am doing mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your model, you have to create an initializer with only Node argument. I think your model need to update to following code:

```
import Vapor
import FluentProvider

final class dataPointStorage: Model, JSONRepresentable, NodeRepresentable {

    //  var _data: dataPointProtocol?
    //    var _data:[dataPointProtocol] = []
    let storage = Storage()
    var id: Node?
    var name: String
    var displayName: String
    public var content: String!


    init(node: Node) {
        self.content = try node.get(dataPointStorage.Keys.content)
        self.displayName = try node.get(dataPointStorage.Keys.displayName)
        self.name = try node.get(dataPointStorage.Keys.displayName)
    }

    struct Keys {
        static let id = "id"
        static let content = "content"
        static let displayName = "displayName"
        static let name = "name"
    }

    //...
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply, it helps, it solves the problem.